# EJB in Liferay Tomcat bundle

Tags: jsf, tomcat, ejb, liferay-6, jpql

i would like to know if i can develop a jsf-portlet with my own ejb's and custom jpql or Hibernate in Liferay Tomcat Bundle.
I know that is possible to bypass service builder and use custom jpql or to use ejb in MVC porltets.
But is it possible with JSF portlets iin Liferay Tomcat Bundle(6.2 CE)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use JSF portlets in the Liferay Tomcat Bundle - why don't give it a try and come back with a _concrete_ question? And please check the meanings of _EJB_ = _Enterprise Java Beans_. These would need an _Enterprise Application Server_. Tomcat is just a _Webcontainer_ which doesn't support EJBs. But I guess you meant _Managed Beans_, which are possible to use with Tomcat.

Comment: [Related post on the Liferay Faces Forums.](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/69563280)

Comment: I know what EJB is, what i didn't know for sure is if liferay bundle uses standard Tomcat or TomcatEE. Also i asked about JSF portlets WITH ejb and custom JPQL or Hibernate, not just JSF portlets only.

Answer (score 1):

The link stiemannkj1  posted covers this subject in detail.

It is possible to use custom Hibernate and Spring in a  JSF liferay portlet, however, it may cause serious problems if you try to manipulate the same  entities from another portlet.
Same goes for EJB, and also you need TomcatEE for this.

If you really want to do this, you have to ensure entities - EJB's are managed by only one portlet, or use Rest/SOAP services for the retrieval of those(which also adds complexity in your system).
You can avoid all that by using Liferay's Service Builder.

I am going to try it though, at least the Hibernate/Services and i am going to share the result soon.